# PHP - PDO fetch loop

Tags: php, pdo

I think I'm losing my mind here.

This is the code. (It's a simplified version of what I am actually trying to do in order to demonstrate the point.)

```
$STH = $DBH->query("SELECT * FROM help");
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    echo $row['text'];
    $help_text = $row['text'];
}
echo "->";
echo $help_text;
echo "<-";
```

The db connection to the MySQL db using the handle DBH is fine (not listed). The query works fine. The echo of `$row['text']` within the loop works fine multiple times. However, the echo of `$help_text` between `->` and `<-` does nothing, resulting in `-><-` being displayed. I would expect the echo to show the last instance of `$row['text']`.

Why is this not working, please?!

Comment: can you show us what this query returns, if the last row is empty, then help_text will be empty too

Comment: Unless I'm missing something very obvious, there's nothing in your code that unsets `$help_text`. The issue must be somewhere else. Additionally, use `var_dump()` to inspect its value rather than plain `echo`.

Comment: Off-topic: note that `PDOStatement` implements [`Traversable`](http://php.net/Traversable), so you can use a `foreach` loop to iterate over results: `foreach ($STH as $row) { ... }`.

Comment: is it possible that `$row['text']` is a reference variable which becomes undefined once the cursor passes the end of the result set?

Comment: SergeS - you have nailed it! The last row had an empty value for 'text'. Sorry and thank you for the advice everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to declare it outside the loop

```
$help_text = "";
while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    echo $row['text'];
    $help_text .= $row['text'];
}
echo "->";
echo $help_text;
echo "<-";
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to concatenate all values.

Comment: I added  $help_text = "a"; echo $help_text; before the loop. The echo before the loop produces an a. After the loop it still leaves the -><- unseparated. I also tried the following: while ($a<3) {$b = $a; $a++;} echo "b = $b"; The echo produces "b=2" regardless of whether you declare $b before the loop or not.