# PHP and Mysql while loop

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, session

I have a mysql table with orders. I am trying to loop through the orders table and select individual client orders according to their user id and display the orders on their client accounts. However, my code below  just prints the first row and repeats it endlessly jaming my browser every time.

what is wrong with this and how to i solve it

```
<?php
$records = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM orders WHERE user_id= :id');
 $records-> bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
 $records->execute();
 $results=$records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 $i=0;
    while($i<=$results):    

        $i++;
 ?> 
<h3>Your Orders</h3>
<table >
    <tr >
        <th>Order Number</th><th>Academic Level</th><th>Order Details</th>Manage Order</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>#SJ<?=$results['id']; ?> </td><td><?=$results['academic_level']; ?></td><td ><?=$results['details']; ?></td>

    </tr>
</table>
<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: `$records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` will fetch only one (the first) row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - PDO fetch loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739423/php-pdo-fetch-loop)

Answer (score 2):

Remove all `$i` related code. Just move your `fetch` statement to **while condition**, like the following:

```
while( $results=$records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Comment: @PeterFlanders happy to help. You may accept this as answer, and also upvote :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the html code in the while loop because you want to display all of the orders.

I'm using this method, try this out.

Start while in first php section

```
<?php
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE username = '$username' ");
$sql->execute();

   while($results=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

?>
```

After that the html section coming:

```
<h3>Your Orders</h3>
<table >
    <tr >
        <th>Order Number</th><th>Academic Level</th><th>Order Details</th>Manage Order</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $results['id']; ?> </td><td><?php echo $results['academic_level']; ?></td><td ><?php echo $results['details']; ?></td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

and here the ending

```
<?php
}
?>
```